# Take data from a text file and insert the data into another file

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to write a program in C to take the data from the input.txt file and insert it into the record.txt file in the ascending order of the students’ ID.

Content of input.txt:

```
1
2012 Bob CS21
1999 Teddy CS35
2
3
2001 Eric CS11
2011 CS12 CS87
```

Content of record.txt:

```
1287 Nancy CS11
1865 Brown CS33
```

When I run the program, the following data from input.txt is supposed to be inserted into the record.file(valid data with students' ID, name and course):

```
2012 Bob CS21
1999 Teddy CS35
2001 Eric CS11
```

Then the content of record.txt file after insertion(ascending order):

```
1287 Nancy CS11
1865 Brown CS33
1999 Teddy CS35
2001 Eric CS11
2012 Bob CS21
```

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100

typedef struct {
int id;
    char name[20];
    char course[5];
} Student;

int read_records(Student s[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    int i=0;
    fp = fopen("record.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File doesn't exist\n");
        return 0;
    }
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        fscanf(fp, "%d %s %s\n", &s[i].id, s[i].name, s[i].course);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return i;
}

void write_records(Student s[], int n) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("record.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File doesn't exist\n");
        return;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        fprintf(fp, "%d %s %s\n", s[i].id, s[i].name, s[i].course);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void insert_records(Student s[], int n) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File doesn't exist\n");
        return;
    }
    int i=n;
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        fscanf(fp, "%d %s %s\n", &s[i].id, s[i].name, s[i].course);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    write_records(s, i);
    printf("Insertion is done.\n");
}
void display_records(Student s[], int n) {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%d %s %s\n", s[i].id, s[i].name, s[i].course);
    }
}
int main() {
    int n;
    Student s[MAX];
    n = read_records(s);
    int opt;
    while (1) {
        printf("1. Insert\n");
        printf("2. Display\n");
        printf("3. Exit\n");
        printf("Choose an option: ");
        scanf("%d", &opt);
        switch(opt) {
            case 1: insert_records(s, n);
                    break;
            case 2: display_records(s, n);
                    break;
            case 3: exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program, the user will be asked to choose an option.

If I enter 2, it will display the content of record.txt. And it works well, as I expected.

If I enter 1, the insertion should be performed and "Insertion is done" will be printed. However, the program doesn't work as I expected. It just displays nothing.

I am confused about that, and I would like to know how to fix the program.

Comment: Obligatory aside: [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2505965)

Comment: Another: [What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string) The format specifiers you use automatically filter leading whitespace (but `%c` and `%[]` would not).

Answer (score 0):

This loop

```
while (!feof(fp)) {
    fscanf(fp, "%d %s %s\n", &s[i].id, s[i].name, s[i].course);
    i++;
}
```

will run indefinitely<sup>1</sup> because when `fscanf` encounters input it cannot convert, that input is left in the stream. The file will never exhaust.

With the file

```
1
2012 Bob CS21
1999 Teddy CS35
2
3
2001 Eric CS11
2011 CS12 CS87
```

the first `fscanf` call will convert `1 "2012" "Bob"`. The second call and so on will fail to convert `CS21` into an integer.

Additionally, see [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2505965).

Also note that an unbounded `%s` specifier in `*scanf` functions is as [dangerous as `gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2505965). Use a [*field-width specifier*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to limit the amount of data that can be read into your buffers. This should be the maximum allowed *string length*, and should be at most the size of your buffer minus one, leaving room for the null-terminating byte. (i.e., `char s[256]; scanf("%255s", s);`).

The solution is to never ignore the return values of the `fscanf` family of functions. Use these return values to determine how your program should proceed. If `fscanf` fails to match the expected number of *conversions*, you must be ready to clean up the input stream. This usually means consuming characters until the end of a line is found.

This is easier said than done, however. As seen above, the way `%s` skips whitespace (including newline characters) means it can overreach looking for valid characters.

The general suggestion is to avoid `scanf/fscanf`, and instead read entire lines with `fgets` and then parse those lines with `sscanf` (or other tools).

In practice this looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INPUT "input.txt"

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(INPUT, "r");

    if (!file) {
        perror(INPUT);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    struct {
        int id;
        char name[32];
        char course[16];
    } student;

    char buffer[512];

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file)) {
        int cv = sscanf(buffer, "%d%31s%15s",
                &student.id, student.name, student.course);

        if (3 == cv) {
            /* three successful conversions, do whatever with `student` */
            printf("%s<%d> [%s]\n",
                    student.name, student.id, student.course);
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

With your `input.txt` file this prints:

```
Bob<2012> [CS21]
Teddy<1999> [CS35]
Eric<2001> [CS11]
CS12<2011> [CS87]
```

Once you know `sscanf` succeeded in parsing the expected number of conversions you can move on to validating the record (e.g., *"CS12"* is an invalid name, per your examples, and you probably need a way to avoid duplicate entries).

In your code you should only increment `i` after making sure all these steps are followed.

After you have your merged list of records, you should use [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) to sort the array with a comparison function such as

```
int student_sort(const void *va, const void *vb)
{
    const Student *a = va, *b = vb;

    return (a->id > b->id) - (a->id < b->id);
}
```

before writing the records out.

---

<sup>1.</sup> `i` will eventually overflow, invoking [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). The outcome of the program after this point cannot be generally reasoned about.